# Check Position of vtkActor before insert new vtkActor

Tags: c#, vtk

I'm working with vtk (c #) to develop my dissertation.

I am creating a lot of objects (vtkSphereSource) in space randomly.

In a certain area can not exist objects. How can I check before including these objects?

I'm testing vtkCleanPolyData and vtkAppendPolyData, but without success.

With regards
Renato

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO, generally speaking questions related to specific coding problems get better responses when you show your code and the specific error and or exception message you receive when compiling and or running your code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen vtkActor::GetPosition()?

http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkProp3D.html#aa5a5e153d3f7f2005b872623d615e8bb

Comment: Thanks Doria, I'll check and feedback soon.